# Ideas on Implementing .NET Properties in T-SQL

Tags: .net, vb.net, t-sql

As I design my system using VB.NET with SQL Server/T-SQL I'm always struck by what seems to me an obvious gap, namely VB Class Properties.

Say I have a table Employee with columns:

```
First varchar  
Last varchar  
KnowsSPANISH bit  
KnowsGERMAN bit
```

In VB I might have a class like:

```
Class Employee  
  Public First as string  
  Public Last as string  
  Public KnowsSPANISH as boolean  
  Public KnowsGERMAN as boolean  

  Public Readonly Property SpeaksAForeignLanguage  
    Get  
     If KnowsSPANISH or KnowsGERMAN return True else return False   
    End Get  
  End Property  
End Class
```

So my property `SpeaksAForeignLanguage` depends on two fields currently. Perhaps someday this will change and more fields or conditions might come into play.  THAT'S THE WHOLE REASON for using properties.

Now if I need the equivalent of my property in SQL for whatever reason there's no way to do it other than to recode some SELECT statement using the two Knows... columns.

Has anyone found a clean way to deal with this?

Comment: Have you read about [views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database))?

Comment: Also [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241)!

Comment: Interesting. So create a view to mimic your class (the properties at least)?  That's not a bad idea in that you'd only have to maintain properties in two spots.

Comment: Computed Columns! Doh, completely forgot about those.  I do recall there being performance hits with both views and computed columns. I know we try to minimize views, but maybe we shouldn't. have you experienced any perf hits from computed columns?

Comment: I have never personally encountered a performance issue stemming from computed columns. I use them reasonably often, but I only use them for very simple calculations.  If it is an issue, you can set the PERSISTED flag, which I think is designed to help with performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another table, say, KnownLanguages, with columns First, Last and Language and join it to the Employee table on First and Last, or I suppose there might be a column EmployeeNumber which you could use for the key between them.

Comment: Good generalized approach.  Maybe use Iden as PK.